# When does loadjava utility skip a class?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, loadjava

I tried to load Zebra Crossing Bar Code Library in Oracle 12c environment. Most of the class files are created and loaded but there are some that are skipped. What does this skipping mean? Does it mean that loadjava utility didn't process given class files at all or does it mean that it has loaded but not compiled?

**verbose log:**

```
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/AlignmentPatternFinder
creating : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/Detector
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/Detector
creating : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPattern
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPattern
creating : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPatternFinder$1
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPatternFinder$1
creating : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPatternFinder$CenterComparator
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPatternFinder$CenterComparator
creating : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPatternFinder$FurthestFromAverageComparator
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPatternFinder$FurthestFromAverageComparator
creating : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPatternFinder
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPatternFinder
creating : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPatternInfo
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPatternInfo
creating : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/BlockPair
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/BlockPair
creating : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/ByteMatrix
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/ByteMatrix
creating : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/Encoder
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/Encoder
creating : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/MaskUtil
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/MaskUtil
creating : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/MatrixUtil
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/MatrixUtil
creating : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/QRCode
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/QRCode
creating : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/QRCodeReader
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/QRCodeReader
creating : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/QRCodeWriter
loading  : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/QRCodeWriter
creating : class com/google/zxing/Reader
loading  : class com/google/zxing/Reader
creating : class com/google/zxing/ReaderException
loading  : class com/google/zxing/ReaderException
creating : class com/google/zxing/Result
loading  : class com/google/zxing/Result
creating : class com/google/zxing/ResultMetadataType
loading  : class com/google/zxing/ResultMetadataType
creating : class com/google/zxing/ResultPoint
loading  : class com/google/zxing/ResultPoint
creating : class com/google/zxing/ResultPointCallback
loading  : class com/google/zxing/ResultPointCallback
creating : class com/google/zxing/Writer
loading  : class com/google/zxing/Writer
creating : class com/google/zxing/WriterException
loading  : class com/google/zxing/WriterException
creating : resource META-INF/maven/com.google.zxing/core/pom.xml
loading  : resource META-INF/maven/com.google.zxing/core/pom.xml
creating : resource META-INF/maven/com.google.zxing/core/pom.properties
loading  : resource META-INF/maven/com.google.zxing/core/pom.properties
resolving: class com/google/zxing/aztec/AztecDetectorResult
resolving: class com/google/zxing/aztec/AztecReader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/aztec/decoder/Decoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/aztec/detector/Detector$1
skipping : class com/google/zxing/aztec/detector/Detector$Point
skipping : class com/google/zxing/aztec/detector/Detector
skipping : class com/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat
skipping : class com/google/zxing/Binarizer
skipping : class com/google/zxing/BinaryBitmap
skipping : class com/google/zxing/ChecksumException
resolving: class com/google/zxing/client/result/AbstractDoCoMoResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/AddressBookAUResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/AddressBookDoCoMoResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/AddressBookParsedResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/BizcardResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/BookmarkDoCoMoResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/CalendarParsedResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/EmailAddressParsedResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/EmailAddressResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/EmailDoCoMoResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/ExpandedProductParsedResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/ExpandedProductResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/GeoParsedResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/GeoResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/ISBNParsedResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/ISBNResultParser
resolving: class com/google/zxing/client/result/optional/AbstractNDEFResultParser
resolving: class com/google/zxing/client/result/optional/NDEFRecord
resolving: class com/google/zxing/client/result/optional/NDEFSmartPosterParsedResult
resolving: class com/google/zxing/client/result/optional/NDEFSmartPosterResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/optional/NDEFTextResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/optional/NDEFURIResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/ParsedResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/ParsedResultType
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/ProductParsedResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/ProductResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/ResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/SMSMMSResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/SMSParsedResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/SMSTOMMSTOResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/SMTPResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/TelParsedResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/TelResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/TextParsedResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/URIParsedResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/URIResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/URLTOResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/VCardResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/VEventResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/WifiParsedResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/client/result/WifiResultParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/common/BitArray
skipping : class com/google/zxing/common/BitMatrix
resolving: class com/google/zxing/common/BitSource
resolving: class com/google/zxing/common/CharacterSetECI
resolving: class com/google/zxing/common/Collections
skipping : class com/google/zxing/common/Comparator
skipping : class com/google/zxing/common/DecoderResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/common/DefaultGridSampler
resolving: class com/google/zxing/common/detector/MonochromeRectangleDetector
skipping : class com/google/zxing/common/detector/WhiteRectangleDetector
skipping : class com/google/zxing/common/DetectorResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/common/ECI
resolving: class com/google/zxing/common/GlobalHistogramBinarizer
skipping : class com/google/zxing/common/GridSampler
resolving: class com/google/zxing/common/HybridBinarizer
skipping : class com/google/zxing/common/PerspectiveTransform
skipping : class com/google/zxing/common/reedsolomon/GenericGF
skipping : class com/google/zxing/common/reedsolomon/GenericGFPoly
skipping : class com/google/zxing/common/reedsolomon/ReedSolomonDecoder
resolving: class com/google/zxing/common/reedsolomon/ReedSolomonEncoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/common/reedsolomon/ReedSolomonException
resolving: class com/google/zxing/common/StringUtils
resolving: class com/google/zxing/datamatrix/DataMatrixReader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/datamatrix/decoder/BitMatrixParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/datamatrix/decoder/DataBlock
skipping : class com/google/zxing/datamatrix/decoder/DecodedBitStreamParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/datamatrix/decoder/Decoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/datamatrix/decoder/Version$1
skipping : class com/google/zxing/datamatrix/decoder/Version$ECB
skipping : class com/google/zxing/datamatrix/decoder/Version$ECBlocks
skipping : class com/google/zxing/datamatrix/decoder/Version
skipping : class com/google/zxing/datamatrix/detector/Detector$1
skipping : class com/google/zxing/datamatrix/detector/Detector$ResultPointsAndTransitions
skipping : class com/google/zxing/datamatrix/detector/Detector$ResultPointsAndTransitionsComparator
skipping : class com/google/zxing/datamatrix/detector/Detector
skipping : class com/google/zxing/DecodeHintType
resolving: class com/google/zxing/EncodeHintType
skipping : class com/google/zxing/FormatException
skipping : class com/google/zxing/LuminanceSource
resolving: class com/google/zxing/multi/ByQuadrantReader
resolving: class com/google/zxing/multi/GenericMultipleBarcodeReader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/multi/MultipleBarcodeReader
resolving: class com/google/zxing/multi/qrcode/detector/MultiDetector
skipping : class com/google/zxing/multi/qrcode/detector/MultiFinderPatternFinder$1
skipping : class com/google/zxing/multi/qrcode/detector/MultiFinderPatternFinder$ModuleSizeComparator
skipping : class com/google/zxing/multi/qrcode/detector/MultiFinderPatternFinder
resolving: class com/google/zxing/multi/qrcode/QRCodeMultiReader
resolving: class com/google/zxing/MultiFormatReader
resolving: class com/google/zxing/MultiFormatWriter
skipping : class com/google/zxing/NotFoundException
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/CodaBarReader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/Code128Reader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/Code128Writer
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/Code39Reader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/Code39Writer
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/Code93Reader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/EAN13Reader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/EAN13Writer
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/EAN8Reader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/EAN8Writer
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/EANManufacturerOrgSupport
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/ITFReader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/ITFWriter
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/MultiFormatOneDReader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/MultiFormatUPCEANReader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/OneDReader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/AbstractRSSReader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/DataCharacter
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/BitArrayBuilder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/AbstractExpandedDecoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/AI013103decoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/AI01320xDecoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/AI01392xDecoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/AI01393xDecoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/AI013x0x1xDecoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/AI013x0xDecoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/AI01AndOtherAIs
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/AI01decoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/AI01weightDecoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/AnyAIDecoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/BlockParsedResult
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/CurrentParsingState
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/DecodedChar
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/DecodedInformation
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/DecodedNumeric
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/DecodedObject
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/FieldParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/decoders/GeneralAppIdDecoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/ExpandedPair
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/expanded/RSSExpandedReader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/FinderPattern
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/Pair
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/RSS14Reader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/rss/RSSUtils
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/UPCAReader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/UPCAWriter
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/UPCEANExtensionSupport
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/UPCEANReader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/UPCEANWriter
skipping : class com/google/zxing/oned/UPCEReader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/pdf417/decoder/BitMatrixParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/pdf417/decoder/DecodedBitStreamParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/pdf417/decoder/Decoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/pdf417/detector/Detector
skipping : class com/google/zxing/pdf417/PDF417Reader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/BitMatrixParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/DataBlock
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/DataMask$1
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/DataMask$DataMask000
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/DataMask$DataMask001
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/DataMask$DataMask010
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/DataMask$DataMask011
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/DataMask$DataMask100
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/DataMask$DataMask101
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/DataMask$DataMask110
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/DataMask$DataMask111
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/DataMask
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/DecodedBitStreamParser
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/Decoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/ErrorCorrectionLevel
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/FormatInformation
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/Mode
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/Version$ECB
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/Version$ECBlocks
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/Version
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/AlignmentPattern
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/AlignmentPatternFinder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/Detector
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPattern
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPatternFinder$1
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPatternFinder$CenterComparator
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPatternFinder$FurthestFromAverageComparator
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPatternFinder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/detector/FinderPatternInfo
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/BlockPair
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/ByteMatrix
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/Encoder
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/MaskUtil
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/MatrixUtil
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/QRCode
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/QRCodeReader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/qrcode/QRCodeWriter
skipping : class com/google/zxing/Reader
skipping : class com/google/zxing/ReaderException
skipping : class com/google/zxing/Result
skipping : class com/google/zxing/ResultMetadataType
skipping : class com/google/zxing/ResultPoint
skipping : class com/google/zxing/ResultPointCallback
skipping : class com/google/zxing/Writer
skipping : class com/google/zxing/WriterException
skipping : resource META-INF/maven/com.google.zxing/core/pom.xml
skipping : resource META-INF/maven/com.google.zxing/core/pom.properties
The following operations failed
    resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF: creation (createFailed)
exiting  : Failures occurred during processing
```